# Some problems with converting char array to string

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin, char

Good day, I'm starter and I have some problem:

I want to convert this `"ромка"` or this `"роМка"` to `"Ромка"` using this code. My code is OK. I have problem with `toString()`.

> Rewrite string using only one first upper char.
>   Problem with converting `charArray` to `String`

```
var name = "ромка"
var charName = name.toLowerCase().toCharArray()
charName[0] = charName[0].toUpperCase()

name = charName.toString()
```

**Results:**

`charName: {'Р', 'о', 'м', 'к', 'а'}`

`name == "[C@93ec54"`

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncb6V.png)

Comment: Do `name = charName[0].toString()` instead of `charName.toString()` as it is an Array and not a string

Comment: That'll just give you "Р" as that's the first character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    var name = "ромка"
    var charName = name.toLowerCase().toCharArray()
    charName[0] = charName[0].toUpperCase()

    name = String(charName)
```

Comment: String(charName) it's working, but why? I have problem with `toString()`

Comment: @RomanShubenko Are you sure you are using a Kotlin String class?

Comment: Hmm, maybe no, maybe yes:)

Comment: To string on Arrays just returns a debug representation of the array as you've seen. To string is a property of all arrays, not one of char arrays designed to convert it back to a String.

Answer (score 4):

```
var name = "ромка"
val result = name.toLowerCase().capitalize()
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `toString()` works this way is that in run time Kotlin arrays are represented with JVM array types, so for example `CharArray` is `char[]` in run time. Those JVM types do not provide meaningful implementations of `toString`, `equals`, and `hashCode` methods.

Instead Kotlin provides the extension functions `contentToString`, `contentEquals` and `contentHashCode` for arrays. These functions are implemented so as if the array was a list, for example `contentToString` would return `[Р, о, м, к, а]` for the array from the question.

However, if you want to concatenate all chars in a char array to a string, you should use another function: either `String(CharArray)` available in Kotlin/JVM, or the experimental extension `CharArray.concatToString()` available for all platforms since Kotlin 1.3.40.

Finally, if your task is to capitalize the first character, then `capitalize` function will do all these manipulations for you, as @Francesc has suggested in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56908103/some-problems-with-converting-char-array-to-string/56908290#56908290).